# How can one iterate with this JSON response file

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

As said above, I don't know how to use this kind of JSON response from my server-side php which I got by using this code `echo json_encode(array_merge($outp, $outp2));`

```
[
    {
        "stuid":"12",
        "stuname":"Velino Meratis",
        "stucourse":"BSIT",
        "stustat":"0",
        "stulyear":"4",
        "stulog":"feb 16 2017"
    },
    {
        "stuid":"13",
        "stuname":"Alana Melker",
        "stucourse":"BSCE",
        "stustat":"1",
        "stulyear":"5",
        "stulog":"feb 16 2017"
    },
    {
        "stuid":"12",
        "cname":"InfoTech000",
        "clog":"1"
    },
    {
        "stuid":"12",
        "cname":"InfoTech001",
        "clog":"2"
    },
    {
        "stuid":"12",
        "cname":"C101",
        "clog":"3"
    },
    {
        "stuid":"13",
        "cname":"CE000",
        "clog":"4"
    },
    {
        "stuid":"13",
        "cname":"CE001",
        "clog":"5"
    },
    {
        "stuid":"13",
        "cname":"C101",
        "clog":"6"
    }
]
```

If I use this code in my client side javascript

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    students = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    students.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.stuid);
    x = item.stuid;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x + " " + item.stuname + "<br>" + item.cname + "<br>";
    });
}
```

it just ends up giving me this:-

```
12 Velino Meratis
undefined
13 Alana Melker
undefined
```

Somehow I can iterate the `stuid` and the `stuname`but it won't allow them to contain the `cname` as an array with them.

How can I turn that into something like this:-

```
12 Velino Meratis
InfoTech000, InfoTech001, C101
13 Alana Melker
CE000, CE001, C101
```

Can someone Help and Elaborate on this?

Comment: As you can see, all items don't have all the params you're trying to use.

Comment: is the `stuid` not enough or something?

Comment: You're trying to use `cname` and `stuname` on _every_ object in the array. If you look at the json data, all objects don't have both (actually none have both) those properties so trying to use them will give you "undefined" when they don't exist.

Comment: Where does the json come from? If you're creating it yourself, I would recommend a better data structure.

Comment: it's already said at the very start... 0_0 I got the data fro my server-side php. And also what you're saying is that both sides must have the same object name but one can have a null or empty object value? Seriously though it's already past 11 here and you're so cryptic XD

Comment: No. I'm saying that you should build one object per student, containing all the data connected to that student. If a property can have multiple values, make it an array with those values. Also make sure all student objects have the same set of properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the array contains the key or not, that way you will be saved from "undefined" error.

You can do it this way

```
if(item.hasOwnProperty('cname'))
{
console.log(item.cname);
}
```

You can use this for stuname or other keys also.

Comment: sorry dude but it's pretty much limited to the first two objects that have `stuname` otherwise it just turns out as undefined :/

Comment: use the same solution for "stuname" also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge `student` objects in your array by unique IDs. One way to do this is to add new `stuid`s to an array and merge it with subsequent items with same `stuid`. Once you have array of unique students, you can proceed with other goals.

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var students_raw = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var students = [];

    students_raw.forEach(function(item){
        var existing = students.find($item => item.stuid === $item.stuid);

        if (existing) {
            existing = Object.assign({}, existing, item);
        } else {
            students.push(item);
        }
    });

    // your print loop
    students.forEach(function(item) {
        var x = item.stuid;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x + " " + item.stuname + "<br>" + item.cname + "<br>";
    });
}
```

Please note: [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) are not supported widely. you may need to polyfill these methods

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This answer assumes you're willing and able to change the data coming from PHP**

Credit where credit is due, this is an extension of @Magnus Eriksson's comment.

It would be preferable to keep the relevant data associated with each other. You should get better flexibility with well-formed data. Ideally, you should do this server side and present the data to the client already well formatted.

You should try and achieve something similar to the following for your output:

```
[{
    "stuid": "12",
    "stuname": "Velino Meratis",
    "stucourse": "BSIT",
    "stustat": "0",
    "stulyear": "4",
    "stulog": "feb 16 2017",
    "classes": [{
        "cname": "InfoTech000",
        "clog": "1"
    }, {
        "cname": "InfoTech001",
        "clog": "2"
    }, {
        "cname": "C101",
        "clog": "3"
    }]
}, {
    "stuid": "13",
    "stuname": "Alana Melker",
    "stucourse": "BSCE",
    "stustat": "1",
    "stulyear": "5",
    "stulog": "feb 16 2017",
    "classes": [{
        "cname": "CE000",
        "clog": "4"
    }, {
        "cname": "CE001",
        "clog": "5"
    }, {
        "cname": "C101",
        "clog": "6"
    }]
}];
```

**Note** I've used classes as the property name as it appears we are working with Courses and their classes.

Your javascript will now look like:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    students = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    students.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.stuid);
    x = item.stuid;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x + " " + item.stuname + "<br>" + item.classes.map(function(elem){
return elem.cname;}).join(",") + "<br>";
    });
}
```

Note the `map` function won't work in IE8 and lower.

Now for a working example:

```js
var students = [{
 "stuid": "12",
 "stuname": "Velino Meratis",
 "stucourse": "BSIT",
 "stustat": "0",
 "stulyear": "4",
 "stulog": "feb 16 2017",
 "classes": [{
  "cname": "InfoTech000",
  "clog": "1"
 }, {
  "cname": "InfoTech001",
  "clog": "2"
 }, {
  "cname": "C101",
  "clog": "3"
 }]
}, {
 "stuid": "13",
 "stuname": "Alana Melker",
 "stucourse": "BSCE",
 "stustat": "1",
 "stulyear": "5",
 "stulog": "feb 16 2017",
 "classes": [{
  "cname": "CE000",
  "clog": "4"
 }, {
  "cname": "CE001",
  "clog": "5"
 }, {
  "cname": "C101",
  "clog": "6"
 }]
}];


students.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.stuid);
    x = item.stuid;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += x + " " + item.stuname + "<br>" + item.classes.map(function(elem){
return elem.cname;}).join(",") + "<br>";
    });
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

As mentioned in other answers and comments, the issue with your existing code, is not all objects in your json array have the property you're referencing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this once also

**HTML**

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var dataJSON = [
{
    "stuid":"12",
    "stuname":"Velino Meratis",
    "stucourse":"BSIT",
    "stustat":"0",
    "stulyear":"4",
    "stulog":"feb 16 2017"
},
{
    "stuid":"13",
    "stuname":"Alana Melker",
    "stucourse":"BSCE",
    "stustat":"1",
    "stulyear":"5",
    "stulog":"feb 16 2017"
},
{
    "stuid":"12",
    "cname":"InfoTech000",
    "clog":"1"
},
{
    "stuid":"12",
    "cname":"InfoTech001",
    "clog":"2"
},
{
    "stuid":"12",
    "cname":"C101",
    "clog":"3"
},
{
    "stuid":"13",
    "cname":"CE000",
    "clog":"4"
},
{
    "stuid":"13",
    "cname":"CE001",
    "clog":"5"
},
{
    "stuid":"13",
    "cname":"C101",
    "clog":"6"
}
]   ;
 var arr = {};
 for(var i = 0 ; i< dataJSON.length ; i++){
    var ele = dataJSON[i];
    if(arr[ ele.stuid ]==undefined){
        arr[ ele.stuid ] = {}; 
    }
    arr[ ele.stuid ]['stuid'] = ele.stuid;
    if(ele.stuname!=undefined){
       arr[ ele.stuid ]['stuname'] = ele.stuname;
    }
    if(arr[ ele.stuid ]['cname'] == undefined){
       arr[ ele.stuid ]['cname'] = [];
    }
    if(ele.cname!=undefined){
       arr[ ele.stuid ]['cname'].push(ele.cname);
    }
 }
 var str = '';
 for(var key in arr){
    var obj = arr[key];
    str += obj['stuid'] +" "+obj['stuname']+'<br/>';
    str += obj['cname'].toString()+'<br/>';
 }
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
```

Thanks,